# How can one use conda, without using Anaconda prompt, and without adding to the PATH?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, anaconda, conda

Anaconda no longer recommends it be added to the PATH, and it instead recommends using Anaconda Prompt.

Well Anaconda Prompt lacks the features of good alternatives (i.e. tabs, and many more).

So to use an alternative to Anaconda Prompt, how would one still access the conda (and pip, etc.) package manager, without violating the recommendation to not add to PATH?

Comment: If you're an experienced enough user to be using a replacement command prompt on Windows, you're probably not the intended target of that recommendation (although I didn't write that message, so I don't know what their intention is/was). That said, you could always type the full path to the command, or set the PATH in the specific command prompt you have open with [SET](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to achieve something such as creating a terminal profile to directly open conda prompt in the windows terminal, without adding it to path, you can do it in the following way:

first, create a new profile on the windows terminal and set the startup directory to your anaconda folder. (Usually, c:/Users/{user}/Annaconda)

Then, you can change the command line to activate any conda environment. If you dont have any, then the default is base. This can be done by:
cmd.exe /k "conda activate base"

Save and start. this now opens a terminal which is running conda. U can change directories, while still having access to all of the conda functions.

Hope it helps.